# Rails array transfer to new join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, associations, rails-activerecord, rails-migrations

I have a table `Exercise` and I'm transferring arrays from a column, `dynamic`, to a new join table `ExerciseDynamicMuscle`. This way each `:id` in the array becomes it's own object/record. I've tested it and it works or at least when checking the records it has transferred correctly, I'm just curious if there is anything else I should add or look out for?

Migration info for table being transferred to:

```
create_table :exercise_dynamic_muscles do |t|
  t.belongs_to :exercise
  t.belongs_to :muscle

  t.timestamps
end
```

Migration created to do the transfer:

```
Exercise.find_each do |e|
  e.dynamic.each do |mu|
    ExerciseDynamicMuscle.create(
      muscle_id: mu, 
      exercise_id: e.id  
    )
  end
end
```

The ExerciseDynamicMuscle schema:

```
  create_table "exercise_dynamic_muscles", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "exercise_id"
    t.bigint "muscle_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["exercise_id"], name: "index_exercise_dynamic_muscles_on_exercise_id"
    t.index ["muscle_id"], name: "index_exercise_dynamic_muscles_on_muscle_id"
  end
```

Once the data is transferred I plan to drop the columns via another migration:

```
remove_column :exercises, :dynamic
```

So there will be two separate migrations:

- One to transfer the data
- One to drop the columns

Comment: well I guess if you say it works, then you've nailed it! I don't know what `Boo` is, and I don't know what Exercise#dynamic returns, so we can't comment on whether it looks right or not.

Comment: LOL it was a place holder when I was writing it and forgot to change it. Updated to reflect right name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually migrations are reversible. To do that, you need something like

```
def up
  create_table :exercise_dynamic_muscles do |t|
    t.belongs_to :exercise
    t.belongs_to :muscle

    t.timestamps
  end

  Exercise.find_each do |e|
    e.dynamic.each do |m_id|
      ExerciseDynamicMuscle.create!(
        muscle_id: m_id,
        exercise_id: e.id
      )
    end
  end

  remove_column :exercises, :dynamic
end

def down
  change_table :exercises do |t|
    t.text :dynamic, array: true, default: []
  end

  ExerciseDynamicMuscle.find_each do |edm|
    exercise = edm.exercise
    exercise.dynamic << edm.muscle_id
    exercise.save!
  end

  drop_table :exercise_dynamic_muscles
end
```

Firstly you create new table, than migrate data to this table from array columns, and finally drop array column

Rollback migration is everything the same but in reverse order only